# How to publish a `geometry_msgs/PoseArray` from the command line?

Tags: ros, robotics

Can anybody give me an example of geometry_msgs/PoseArray message using rostopic pub? I keep on getting errors when i try and interpret the syntax from the ROS documentation, a solid example would be really helpful.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the *desired behaviour*, a *specific problem or error* and the *shortest code necessary to reproduce it* in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Clearly you know nothing about ROS. This is not a debugging question. Why don't you pipe down and look for verification points on another thread?

Comment: If you want your question answered then you need to give more information. Stack overflow is not a place to get example code, it is a place to [ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). My comment was not meant as a criticism, it was meant to help you make your question into one which was more likely to be answered. I would have told you to do exactly the same if you'd asked the question on [Robotics.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this:

```
rostopic pub /my_topic geometry_msgs/PoseArray "{header: {frame_id: 'base_frame'}, poses: [{position: {x: 1.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}, orientation: {x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, w: 1.0}}, {position: {x: 1.1, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}, orientation: {x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, w: 1.0}}]}"
```

This will publish a `PoseArray` message containing two poses to the topic `my_topic`. Furthermore, if you are using bash I believe you can auto-complete the message by hitting tab.